# Run two Loops Simultaneously on Arduino

Tags: 7-segment

I am not able to combine the below two sketches. What I require is to either run both the loops together or find a way to run both the functions inside a single loop.

Sketch 1

```
#include <SevSeg.h>
#include <DS1307RTC.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <Wire.h>

// Create an instance of the object
SevSeg sevseg;
bool militaryTime = false; // true for 24 hour clock

void setup() {
  byte numDigits = 4;
  byte digitPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
  byte segmentPins[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
  bool resistorsOnSegments = false; // 'false' means resistors are on digit pins
  byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_ANODE; // See README.md for options
  bool updateWithDelays = false; // Default. Recommended
  bool leadingZeros = true; // Use 'true' if you'd like to keep the leading zeros

  sevseg.begin(hardwareConfig, numDigits, digitPins, segmentPins, resistorsOnSegments, updateWithDelays, leadingZeros);
  sevseg.setBrightness(90);
}

void loop() {
  tmElements_t tm;
  int time;
  int dot;

  if (RTC.read(tm)) {
    time = tm.Hour * 100;
    if (time > 1200 && militaryTime == false) {
      time = time - 1200;
    }
    if (time == 0 && militaryTime == false) {
      time = 1200;
    }
    time += tm.Minute;
  }

  if ((tm.Second % 2) == 0) {
    dot = 4;
  } else {
    dot = 2;
  }

  //Produce an output on the display
  sevseg.refreshDisplay();
  sevseg.setNumber(time, dot);
}
```

Sketch 2

```
// Change this to the output pin you are using
#define TICK_PIN A0

void setup()
{
  pinMode(TICK_PIN,OUTPUT);
  while (1) {
    tone(TICK_PIN,1000,2);
    delay(1000);
  }
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Comment: The second `loop` is empty. You are already "running" it ...

Comment: @LookAlterno Actually, the 2nd `loop` never executes because of the `while` in `setup`.

Comment: The second loop can actually be in the loop function as well. Either way, I am unable to combine the two to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to get rid of the delay and any other blocking loops. Here is a way to do it.

Define this variable globally.

```
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
```

Then in your first loop, add the following code either to the beginning or the end:

```
if (millis() - lastTime >= 1000 || !lastTime) {
    lastTime = millis();
    tone(TICK_PIN,1000,2);
}
```

Comment: What is the `!lastTime` for ?

Comment: @Jot. `!lastTime` is tested to run the `tone`in the first execution of `loop`. After that, is always false. A common trick to resolve the first execution problem.

Comment: This worked very well

Comment: That looks familiar....just like my answer that was posted 3 hours before yours.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Well, this is a common trick to emulate multitasking on arduino. After looking at yours, it doesn't solve the first execution problem which is done above. You can find this answer almost everywhere, it's not a rocket science.

Comment: That's OK, even though I didn't read your answer beforehand but I can delete my answer if that will make you happy ;)

Comment: Let it go. I've moved on......and the right thing to do is remove your unjustified DV on my answer.

Comment: Not a problem. Waiting for the edit to be approved before I can upvote you again. Also, I couldn't delete this answer because it was accepted.

Comment: @LookAlterno, I never used `!lastTime`. Perhaps I never needed to run something in the first execution of loop. After 50 days it could cause a glitch.

Comment: @Jot. In the world I live in, 50 days without a black-out is quite a record. The longest period between blackouts this year was 17 days. Hours, even days without electricity, That's way I always forget about millis() rollover ... it's just a first world problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fund the easiest way to work on this challenge when you have to deal with a long delay and think you need a second loop, is to make make a counter in the main loop using centiseconds (10 milliseconds) and then trigger your required response when the counter reaches your time like
void loop(void) {
counter=counter +1;
if (counter==100){
tone(TICK_PIN, 1000, 2);
counter =0;
}
....rest of code

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a timer callback.

```cpp
// Include the timer1 library
#include "TimerOne.h"

// Other code here...

void setup()
{
    // Other setup code here....

    // Setup timer
    Timer1.initialize(1000000);          // 1 second
    Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback);    // Set callback
}

void callback()
{
    tone(TICK_PIN, 1000, 2);
}

void loop()
{
    // Code from 1st loop here...
}
```

If that doesn't work (if something else is using timer1) you could just keep track of the time between beeps:

```cpp
uint32_t last_beep = 0;
const int beep_timeout = 1000;

void loop() {
    // Code from first loop here

    uint32_t now = millis();
    if (now - last_beep >= beep_timeout) {
        tone(TICK_PIN, 1000, 2);
        last_beep = now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain?

Comment: You actually read and understood my question better than the accepted answerer. The reason why I did not accept this was simply due to complexity. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score -1):

> Run two Loops Simultaneously on Arduino

in general, the answer depends on your definition of "simultaneously".

But in this case, the answer is "definitively yes", as the other loop is empty.

a generic approach to this kind of questions is:

```
void setup(void) {
  setup1();  //run setup 1
  setup2();  //run setup 2
  ...
}

void loop(void) {
  loop1();  //run loop1
  loop2();  //run loop2
  ...
}
```

this approach would only fail if the original setup() and loop() are written poorly.

Comment: This might work in some cases, but not even closely for my case.